# C# occurrence counting generic list with different property types

Tags: c#, list, generics

I need to count the occurrences of each element in the  "ID" field of a generic list. The result should be the list with an added field called "Quantity".

Suppose the following class is used for the list:

```cs
public class InfoList
{
  public string ID { get; set; }            
  public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
  public double Amount { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine an initial list like the following:

| ID | Purchase date | Amount (USD) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DDD | 30 jul 2025 | 258,225.11 |
| AXC | 10 nov 2023 | 982,383.95 |
| AXC | 12 feb 2031 | -439,130.87 |
| TPV | 05 mar 2023 | 439,715.32 |
| DDD | 8 apr 2024 | -153,893.38 |
| KYR | 24 mar 2023 | -153,893.38 |
| AXC | 10 sep 2026 | 638,031.66 |
| SPM | 26 oct 2023 | -401,815.59 |
| DDD | 08 mar 2023 | -315,099.43 |
| HGP | 30 nov 2025 | -474,749.80 |
| DDD | 02 jul 2024 | -253,726.59 |
| NDS | 06 sep 2029 | 490,035.01 |
| HGP | 24 dec 2026 | 468,006.38 |

The final result should be the following:

| ID | Purchase date | Amount (USD) | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DDD | 30 jul 2025 | 258,225.11 | 4 |
| AXC | 10 nov 2023 | 982,383.95 | 3 |
| AXC | 12 feb 2031 | -439,130.87 | 3 |
| TPV | 05 mar 2023 | 439,715.32 | 1 |
| DDD | 8 apr 2024 | -153,893.38 | 4 |
| KYR | 24 mar 2023 | -153,893.38 | 1 |
| AXC | 10 sep 2026 | 638,031.66 | 3 |
| SPM | 26 oct 2023 | -401,815.59 | 1 |
| DDD | 08 mar 2023 | -315,099.43 | 4 |
| HGP | 30 nov 2025 | -474,749.80 | 2 |
| DDD | 02 jul 2024 | -253,726.59 | 4 |
| NDS | 06 sep 2029 | 490,035.01 | 1 |
| HGP | 24 dec 2026 | 468,006.38 | 2 |

Result should be of type "InfoList" not in a different list or variable.

Comment: The question is unclear. What is the issue?

Comment: So you want to extend the existing result set and also include a total count as a new column based on ID. In that case create a new query that just groups by ID and has a COUNT. Now join that to the existing query by ID and add the new COUNT column to the select. We do expect you to do some of the work but that is the logic behind it. Good luck.

Comment: @Igor You should rename the `Id` property and column then, as it **doesn't** uniquely identify each row.

Comment: @Dai - True but for all I know it is short for something else or domain specific or the teacher (if this is homework which I suspect it is) does not want that. I marked it as out of scope in my head for my comment.

Comment: Does quantity represent how many purchases are being made on a specific date, or how purchases have been made year-to-today?

Comment: Quantity represents ID ocurrences. For instance, "DDD" ID appears 4 times; "AXC" ID appears 3 times...issue is initial list should be completed with final property called "Quantity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that preserves the original order of the list.

```
var initial = new[]
{
    new { ID = "DDD", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("30 jul 2025"), Amount = 258225.11 },
    new { ID = "AXC", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("10 nov 2023"), Amount = 982383.95 },
    new { ID = "AXC", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("12 feb 2031"), Amount = -439130.87 },
    new { ID = "TPV", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("05 mar 2023"), Amount = 439715.32 },
    new { ID = "DDD", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("8 apr 2024"), Amount = -153893.38 },
    new { ID = "KYR", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("24 mar 2023"), Amount = -153893.38 },
    new { ID = "AXC", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("10 sep 2026"), Amount = 638031.66 },
    new { ID = "SPM", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("26 oct 2023"), Amount = -401815.59 },
    new { ID = "DDD", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("08 mar 2023"), Amount = -315099.43 },
    new { ID = "HGP", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("30 nov 2025"), Amount = -474749.80 },
    new { ID = "DDD", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("02 jul 2024"), Amount = -253726.59 },
    new { ID = "NDS", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("06 sep 2029"), Amount = 490035.01 },
    new { ID = "HGP", PurchaseDate = DateTime.Parse("24 dec 2026"), Amount = 468006.38 },
};

var lookup = initial.ToLookup(x => x.ID);

InfoList[] final =
    initial
        .Select(i =>
            new InfoList()
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                PurchaseDate = i.PurchaseDate,
                Amount = i.Amount,
                Quantity = lookup[i.ID].Count(),
            })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: final]

If preserving the initial order isn't important then this works:

```
InfoList[] final =
(
    from i in initial
    group i by i.ID into gis
    from gi in gis
    select new InfoList()
    {
        ID = gi.ID,
        PurchaseDate = gi.PurchaseDate,
        Amount = gi.Amount,
        Quantity = gis.Count(),
    }
).ToArray();
```

---

To do this with an extension method, you could try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> SelectCount<T, U, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, U> countBy, Func<T, int, R> project) =>
    from t in source
    group t by countBy(t) into gts
    from gt in gts
    select project(gt, gts.Count());
```

Then the code looks like this:

```
InfoList[] final =
    initial
        .SelectCount(i => i.ID, (i, q) => new InfoList()
        {
            ID = i.ID,
            PurchaseDate = i.PurchaseDate,
            Amount = i.Amount,
            Quantity = q,
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Let me ask you something Mr Enigmativity: if I had n-generic list<T>, would it be possible to pass those generic lists to method for doing same thing? It should be passed property what occurrence counting will be made. In any case, your answer was quite useful. Thanks a lot gentleman!

Comment: @Pipe - Yes, that's absolutely possible. You want an answer to it?

Comment: Dear Enigmativity, it would be great an answer for that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pipe - I don't know if the extension method helps with readability. But there it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you can track quantities in a dictionary as a separate data structure.

```cs
void main()
{
  List<ItemList> purchaseList = buildItemList();
  Dictionary<string,int> quantity = buildQuantityDictionary(purchaseList);
  printTable(purchaseList, quantity);
}

List<ItemList> buildItemList()
{
  //however you build the itemlist
}

Dictionary<string,int> buildQuantityDictionary(List<ItemList> purchaseList)
{
  Dictionary<string,int> quantity = new Dictionary<string,int>();
  foreach(ItemList item in purchaseList)
  {
    if(!quantity.ContainsKey(item.id))
    {
      quantity.add(item.id,0);
    }
    quantity[item.id]++;
  }
  return quantity;
}

void printTable(List<ItemList> purchaseList, Dictionary<string,int> quantity)
{
  foreach(ItemList item in purchaseList)
  {
    //You'll need to write a ToString() override for your ItemList object.
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ToString()},{quantity[item.id]}");
  }
}
```